# Memorylessness and Geometric cumulative distribution function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X$ be a random variable with values in $\mathbb{N}_{0} = \{0,1,2,...\}$ such, that $P(X \geq n)>0$ for all $n\geq0$ and additionally $$  P(X \geq n+i | X \geq n ) = P(X \geq i) $$ for all all $n,i \geq 0$. ("Memorylessness"). Show that, $X$ posses a geometric cumulative distribution function, i.e. $\exists p \in (0,1): P(X=n)=p(1-p)^n$ for all $n\geq0.$

Comment: Did you search the site? Or perhaps a google search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\forall n,k \in \mathbb{N},P(X \geq n+k)=P(X \geq n)P(X \geq k),$ take $k=1,$
we have $\forall n \in \mathbb{N},P(X \geq n+1)=P(X \geq n)P(X \geq 1).$ 
Let $q=P(X \geq 1),u_n=P(X \geq n),$ so we deduce that $u_{n+1}=qu_n,$ which means that $u_n=q^nu_0=q^n, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}.$

$\forall n \in \mathbb{N},P(X=n)=-P(X \geq n+1)+P(X\geq n)=q^n(1-q).$

Since $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}P(X=n)=1 \neq 0,$ this means there exist $n_0 \in \mathbb{N},P(X=n_0) \neq 0,$ and then $0<1-q<1,$ we deduce that $X$ follows geometric cumulative distribution function with parameter $p:=1-q.$

Comment: Typo in $P(X \geq n+1) = P(X \geq 1)P(X \geq 1)$.